# Simulate unbalanced clustered data

Tags: r, simulation, data-manipulation, data-generation

I want to simulate some unbalanced clustered data. The number of clusters is 20 and the average number of observations is 30. However, I would like to create an unbalanced clustered data per cluster where there are 10% more observations than specified (i.e., 33 rather than 30). I then want to randomly exclude an appropriate number of observations (i.e., 60) to arrive at the specified average number of observations per cluster (i.e., 30). The probability of excluding an observation within each cluster was not uniform (i.e., some clusters had no cases removed and others had more excluded). Therefore in the end I still have 600 observations in total. Anyone knows how to realize that in R? Here is a smaller example dataset. The number of observation per cluster doesn't follow the condition specified above though, I just used this to convey my idea.

```
> y <- rnorm(20)
> x <- rnorm(20)
> z <- rep(1:5, 4)
> w <- rep(1:4, each=5)
> df <- data.frame(id=z,cluster=w,x=x,y=y) #this is a balanced dataset
> df
   id cluster           x           y
1   1       1  0.30003855  0.65325768
2   2       1 -1.00563626 -0.12270866
3   3       1  0.01925927 -0.41367651
4   4       1 -1.07742065 -2.64314895
5   5       1  0.71270333 -0.09294102
6   1       2  1.08477509  0.43028470
7   2       2 -2.22498770  0.53539884
8   3       2  1.23569346 -0.55527835
9   4       2 -1.24104450  1.77950291
10  5       2  0.45476927  0.28642442
11  1       3  0.65990264  0.12631586
12  2       3 -0.19988983  1.27226678
13  3       3 -0.64511396 -0.71846622
14  4       3  0.16532102 -0.45033862
15  5       3  0.43881870  2.39745248
16  1       4  0.88330282  0.01112919
17  2       4 -2.05233698  1.63356842
18  3       4 -1.63637927 -1.43850664
19  4       4  1.43040234 -0.19051680
20  5       4  1.04662885  0.37842390
```

After randomly adding and deleting some data, the unbalanced data become like this:

```
            id   cluster   x     y
       1     1       1  0.895 -0.659 
       2     2       1 -0.160 -0.366 
       3     1       2 -0.528 -0.294 
       4     2       2 -0.919  0.362 
       5     3       2 -0.901 -0.467 
       6     1       3  0.275  0.134 
       7     2       3  0.423  0.534 
       8     3       3  0.929 -0.953 
       9     4       3  1.67   0.668 
      10     5       3  0.286  0.0872
      11     1       4 -0.373 -0.109 
      12     2       4  0.289  0.299 
      13     3       4 -1.43  -0.677 
      14     4       4 -0.884  1.70  
      15     5       4  1.12   0.386 
      16     1       5 -0.723  0.247 
      17     2       5  0.463 -2.59  
      18     3       5  0.234  0.893 
      19     4       5 -0.313 -1.96  
      20     5       5  0.848 -0.0613
```

**EDIT**
This part of the problem solved (credit goes to jay.sf). Next, I want to repeat this process 1000 times and run regression on each generated dataset. However, I don't want to run regression on the whole dataset but rather on some selected clusters with the clusters being selected randomly (can use this function: `df[unlist(cluster[sample.int(k, k, replace = TRUE)], use.names = TRUE), ]`. In the end, I would like to get confidence intervals from those 1000 regressions. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `ncl` be the desired number of clusters. We may generate a sampling space `S` which is a sequence of tolerance `tol` around mean observations per cluster `mnobs`. From that we draw `repeat`etly a random sample of size 1 to obtain a list of clusters `CL`. If the sum of cluster `lengths` meets `ncl*mnobs` we `break` the loop, add random data to the clusters and `rbind` the result.

```
FUN <- function(ncl=20, mnobs=30, tol=.1) {
  S <- do.call(seq.int, as.list(mnobs*(1 + tol*c(-1, 1))))
  repeat({
    CL <- lapply(1:ncl, function(x) rep(x, sample(S, 1, replace=T)))
    if (sum(lengths(CL)) == ncl*mnobs) break
  })
  L <- lapply(seq.int(CL), function(i) {
    id <- seq.int(CL[[i]])
    cbind(id, cluster=i, 
          matrix(rnorm(max(id)*2),,2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("x", "y"))))
  })
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, L)
}
```

**Usage**

```
set.seed(42)
res <- FUN()  ## using defined `arg` defaults
dim(res)
# [1] 600   4

(res.tab <- table(res$cluster))
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 29 29 31 31 30 32 31 30 32 28 28 27 28 31 32 33 31 30 27 30

table(res.tab)
# 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 
#  2  3  2  4  5  3  1

sapply(c("mean", "sd"), function(x) do.call(x, list(res.tab)))
#      mean        sd 
# 30.000000  1.747178
```

**Displayable example**

```
set.seed(42)
FUN(4, 5, tol=.3)  ## tol needs to be adjusted for smaller samples
#    id cluster           x          y
# 1   1       1  1.51152200 -0.0627141
# 2   2       1 -0.09465904  1.3048697
# 3   3       1  2.01842371  2.2866454
# 4   1       2 -1.38886070 -2.4404669
# 5   2       2 -0.27878877  1.3201133
# 6   3       2 -0.13332134 -0.3066386
# 7   4       2  0.63595040 -1.7813084
# 8   5       2 -0.28425292 -0.1719174
# 9   6       2 -2.65645542  1.2146747
# 10  1       3  1.89519346 -0.6399949
# 11  2       3 -0.43046913  0.4554501
# 12  3       3 -0.25726938  0.7048373
# 13  4       3 -1.76316309  1.0351035
# 14  5       3  0.46009735 -0.6089264
# 15  1       4  0.50495512  0.2059986
# 16  2       4 -1.71700868 -0.3610573
# 17  3       4 -0.78445901  0.7581632
# 18  4       4 -0.85090759 -0.7267048
# 19  5       4 -2.41420765 -1.3682810
# 20  6       4  0.03612261  0.4328180
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @jay.sf, as always! I actually found a "seemingly" shortcut answer to the question: first just oversample and then `slice_sample` to arrive at the  sample size as desired.

Comment: @cliu Sure, we may find special packages with functions for almost any particular problem. Learning how to do things from scratch might be more sustainable though, and it prevents from getting addicted :)

Comment: Hi @jay.sf. Sorry that I am asking for your help again but I just edited my question with an updated task of running regression on the generated clustered data. Would you share some code on the implementation? Based on your answer to another question, I wrote this but the function seems to be fixed and wouldn't vary when I later `replicate` it: `BetaClus <- function() {
  clsamp.reg <- df[unlist(cluster[sample.int(k, k, replace = TRUE)], use.names = TRUE), ] x <- unlist(clsamp.reg["x"]) y <- unlist(clsamp.reg["y"]) clusmod <- lm(y ~ x) confint(clusmod, "x", level = 0.95)}`. Thanks!

Comment: @cliu, can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Sure

Answer (score 1):

As per Ben Bolker's request, I am posting my solution but see jay.sf for a more generalizable answer.

```
#First create an oversampled dataset: 
  y <- rnorm(24)
  x <- rnorm(24)
  z <- rep(1:6, 4)
  w <- rep(1:4, each=6)
  df <- data.frame(id=z,cluster=w,x=x,y=y)
#Then just slice_sample to arrive at the sample size as desired
  df %>% slice_sample(n = 20) %>%
  arrange(cluster)
#Or just use base R
  a <- df[sample(nrow(df), 20), ]  
  df2 <- a[order(a$cluster), ]
```